# Possible to use BrowserRouter with React to handle URLs non-pretty URLs?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router, url-routing

I am attempting to bootstrap my React app inside a Wordpress plugin. When the plugin loads, the URL is `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin-name`, and this cannot be changed. I've tried to do URL rewrites and use `/wp-admin/my-plugin-name/`, but it's been a no-go, so unfortunately I have to find another option.

Here is my router:

```
<Router basename="/wp-admin/admin.php">
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <DashboardPage />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/account">
      <AccountPage />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/products">
      <ProductsPage />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Currently the Dashboard (default) loads when I visit `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin-name` in my browser. But if I visit any other page, such as `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin-name%2Fproducts` (note that Wordpress automatically changes `my-plugin-name/products` to `my-plugin-name%2Fproducts`), the Dashboard page still shows.

I've also tried using `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin-name` for `basename` with the same result.

How can I make the other pages loadable? I am able to make this work using `HashRouter`, but I'd like to use `BrowserRouter`.

Answer (score 0):

place

```
 <Route exact path="/">
      <DashboardPage />
    </Route>
```

as your last route in the list

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that does not seem to solve the issue.